# <p> errors -don't understand the missing "li" problem in my paragraph

Tags: paragraph

I keep trying to validate my webpage and I keep getting the same errors below...and all I have are text in paragraphs. They are not meant to be lists or anything like that. See errors below.

> Line 61, Column 3: document type does not allow element "p" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag

```
<p>Try a fun way to raise money for a worthy cause with your neighbors, girl sc…
✉
 Line 62, Column 40: end tag for "li" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
      <a href="#">Read more</a></p></ul><!-- end zachadtext -->
✉
```

> You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
>
> Line 61, Column 1: start tag was here

```
<p>Try a fun way to raise money for a worthy cause with your neighbors, girl sc…
```

Comment: You'll need to post the html, obviously it thinks you have a tag open...

Comment: You need to post a lot more code, try starting at line 50

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you opened a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element prior to the `<p>`.  Such elements can only contain `<li>` elements.  (If you want more detailed help, paste your code somewhere.)

Comment: <div id="container">
<div id="search"> Insert search bar here
</div>  <!-- end search form -->

<div id="nav">
<ul class="mainnavigation">
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="#">NEWS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ZACK PACKS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GET INVOLVED</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ZACH'S STORY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- end Nav -->
<div id="siteName">
<h1></h1>
</div> <!-- end siteName -->
<div id="bluemiddle">
<div id="quicklinks">
<div id="zachad">
<ul class="zachadtext">
<p>Try a fun way

Comment: so the <ul class="zachadtext"> needs to be closed before my paragraph?

Comment: Yes, or you need to put the <p> in an <li>.

Comment: when I close it, I get the below error: end tag for "ul" which is not finished
<ul class="zachadtext"></ul>

Comment: Well, an empty list doesn't really make much sense.  If your list has no entries, there should be no list.